# How to fix this warning messages at compilation on AS400 (C program)?

Tags: c, ibm-midrange

On iSeries (AS400), in a developer environment, when I compile a C or C++ program (under *qsh*, using *gmake* and *ixlc* / not `CRTPGM`)

`ixlc -c mySource.c`

Each time `<math.h>` is used in a source code, pops this series of warnings:

> /QIBM/include/math.h Line 000195 The floating point literal "1.1754943508222875E-38F" is out of range.
>
> /QIBM/include/math.h Line 000208 The floating point literal "1.1754943508222875E-38F" is out of range.
>
> /QIBM/include/math.h Line 000217 The floating point literal "1.1754943508222875E-38F" is out of range.
>
> ... plus 10 more

Which corresponds to any line using `FLT_MIN` , a defined const, from */QIBM/include/float.h* .

```
#define FLT_MIN               1.1754943508222875E-38F
```

But how can I avoid this warning message which floods my compilation logs.

Comment: Don't aim to silence compiler warnings (that way lies bugs). Instead aim to fix code to not trigger the warnings in the first place.

Comment: Show some relevant code, especially what is `_Ans`?

Comment: Removed the c++ tag again. I don't see any relevance.

Comment: Assuming the system uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) then single-precision float values can only have up to seven decimal digits. A double-precision value can have 15. The defined value for `FLT_MIN` in your header file have 16 decimal digits. Which is way too much. Perhaps a bug in the library used?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, declare so `#define FLT_MIN 1.1754943508222875E-38F` . Sadly, it's IBM. Not me.

@πάνταῥεῖ ha, you did. I thought it was me. I compile with a C++ compiler, but yeah, it's unrelevant.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes in a comment, they refer to ANSI/IEEE 754-1985 and  ANSI/IEEE 754R. But they obviously don't fulfill this norm.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Wise, but it's the implementation of the std by IBM. And they don't update it since 2011 on iSeries. Maybe I could just fix it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defined value for `FLT_MIN` in your header file has 16 decimal digits. Which is way too much.

This system uses *IEEE 754*. So single-precision float values can only have up to 7 decimal digits. (And double-precision value can have 15).
The compiler seems to know, but not the `std` sources.

Fix the code in the library.

Take example on other implementations of the `std`, the code in the library should be:

```
#define FLT_EPSILON     1.192093e-07
#define FLT_MIN         1.175494e-38
#define FLT_MAX         3.402823e+38
```

Since this ILE source is protected on iSeries, maybe choose to redirect the symbolic link from `/QIBM/include/float.h` to another source code of your creation. Not necessarily a member, but an IFS file should do the job.